# Прямая речь в предложении

Tags: прямая-речь

Подскажите, правильно ли в этом предложении расставлены знаки препинания : "Иди сюда", - сказал Антон, -"немедленно".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно: "Иди сюда, — сказал Антон, — немедленно".

Правило:

Если на месте разрыва прямой речи не должно быть никакого знака препинания или должны быть знаки середины предложения: запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие, тире, то слова автора выделяются запятой и тире; вторая часть прямой речи начинается со строчной буквы: «**Ты не можешь понять, — шепчу, отозвав Руслана в соседнюю комнату и затворив дверь, — потому, что мы разные существа» (Триф.); «Так, подвяла чуть-чуть, с одного бока, — Ася хихикнула по-молодому, по лицу разбегаются морщинки, — как яблочко лежалое» (Триф.);**

Answer (score 1):

Интересное предложение: ***"Иди сюда немедленно".***  Интонация повествовательная.

Я бы сказала так: Иди сюда! Немедленно! Или: НемЕдленно иди сюда!

Наречие здесь центр высказывания, оно должно быть выделено логическим ударением, а это возможно при парцелляции или инверсии.

Тогда получаем такое оформление:

***"Иди сюда, — сказал Антон. — Немедленно!".***

С другой стороны, надо, конечно, видеть контекст.

Comment: Я просто это на ходу выдумал)